# How to read unicode files in python (not UTF-8)

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

How to read **unicode** files in `python 2.x` (not UTF-8, unknown encoding)

I tried to find a way to read unicode files.
I searched on the Internet for a long long long time.
But I can't find it.
What I found are the way to read files such as encoded as UTF-8.
I know, that when I need to read UTF-8, I can use codecs.

**`codecs.open('unicode2.txt',encoding='utf-8')`**

**Using this I can read UTF-8 files.**
But I want to know how to read unicode files.
Many many post that titled 'the way to read unicode files in python' actually tells a way to read files such as UTF-8, UTF-16.

Why anyone didn't explain a way to read **'UNICODE'** files?

this is an example of hex value of text files I try to read with python.

This is Korean, "`파이썬에서 한글 읽기`"

```
(FF FE) 0C D3 74 C7 6C C3 D0 C5 1C C1 20 00 5C D5 00 AE 20 00 7D C7 30 AE
```

`(FF FE)` means byte order.
And each 2 byte means character. As you can see, space is written as '20 00', not '20'
In unicode, space is written as '20 00'. But UTF-8, space is written as '20'.

There is no way to use codecs like "`codecs.open('unicode2.txt',encoding='**unicode**')`"

Is there really no way to read **"unicode"** files in python?

Comment: There is not really such a thing as a "unicode file".  There are only files with particular unicode encodings.  You need to know what encoding your file is in.  It looks like your file may be in UTF-16.

Comment: You should definitely read this: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on the false premise that a file can be in "Unicode" without being encoded. There's no real solution than to start with learning about unicode and encoding.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that was UTF-16. Now I solved a problem. Really thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3051951 this is a great basic read on the subject http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html , hope you enjoy it :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Really nice read. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is unfortunate that Microsoft tools invariably, misleadingly, provide an encoding option called "Unicode" that is actually UTF-16LE.

Comment: @bobince That's exactly why I was confused about Unicode.

Answer (score 5):

A disk file is a sequence of *bytes* that you can interpret as a text if you use character encoding such as utf-8, utf-16le. "unicode" is not a character encoding.

[There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Your example file might use `utf-16le` encoding:

```
>>> text = u"파이썬"
>>> text.encode('utf-16le')
'\x0c\xd3t\xc7l\xc3'
>>> text.encode('utf-16le').encode('hex')
'0cd374c76cc3'
```

`b'\xff\xfe' == codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE` is a BOM for UTF-16 (LE) character encoding. To read such file, you could use utf-16 encoding (BE or LE are chosen based on BOM):

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('filename', encoding='utf-16') as file:
    text = file.read()
```

Comment: "There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text" is really nice read. I was confused because a code point and UTF-16 looked same. Now I got to know that storing a code point(U+????) as two bytes and deciding which endian to use makes UTF-16. Thank you!